# How to incline the bottom border of a div with background image

Tags: html, css, border, angle

I have a simple div set to be a height of about a full viewport. This div has a background image and a line of text. I would like to incline the bottom border of this div while keeping all the content aligned as per default (horizontally).
I have tried with transform rotate or skew but this rotates the content as well makes background move out of the corners of the div due to the rotation.
Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
This is an example of what I tried with rotated content:

```
<div class="backgrounddiv"><h1 class="title">Title</h1></div>

<style>
.title{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left:40%;
          transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.backgrounddiv{
background:url('media/bgpic.png') scroll no-repeat center/cover;
transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code examples of things you've tried?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: Please explain `incline the bottom border`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use a [pseudo-element](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) as a *mask*. You can set the placement and background colour of the element so that it looks like we're cutting a chunk out of the `<div>` holding your content.

Here's an example snippet. **Run it** to see the result.

Change the `background-color` of the mask to red (or any colour) and remove `overflow: hidden` from the container to get a better idea of what is *actually* happening.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::before{
  content: '';
  width: 200%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10%;
  left: -50%;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I want to do but to a full height, full width div, I am struggling to adapt what you did to that specific case, what should width and height be defined as in this case?

Comment: I've changed `width` and `height` of the pseudo-element to percentages so they should increase as the container size increases. Then just tweak it to how you want it by changing `width`, `height`, `bottom` and `left` of `.container::before`.